# Unresolved external symbol "public: int myclass::get_a (void)" How do I resolve this code? Noobie Q

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, codeblocks, undefined-reference

Noobie programmer here learning C++ for the first time. The following is excerpted code from Teach Yourself C++ 3rd Edition.
I'm dying help me, I'm learning about classes, but I can't get this code to compile on visual studio or on Code::Blocks. :(

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
//I understand this. Headers, etc.
using namespace std;
//and this, name traffic management system
class myclass {
    //private to myclass
    int a;
public:
    void set_a(int num);
    int get_a();
};
/*I understand int a is private/inaccessible from the rest of the code
and void set_a(int num) is the dummy function.*/
void myclass::set_a(int num)
//not sure what this is
{
    a = num;
}
/*self explanatory*/
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    myclass ob1, ob2;

    ob1.set_a(10);
    ob2.set_a(99);

    cout << ob1.get_a() << "\n";
    cout << ob2.get_a() << "\n";

    return -5;
}
/*This is just supposed to output the number 10 and 99 right?? So why isn't it?*/
```

On Visual Studio the full error description is:
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall myclass::get_a(void)" (?get_a@myclass@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _wmain  c:\Users\bernardo pliego\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Chapter 1.5\Chapter 1.5\Chapter 1.5.obj  Chapter 1.5

On Code::Blocks I receive the following error:
In function 'main':
undefined reference to 'my_class::get_a()'

I am in dire need of help, can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't define `get_a`, you only declare it. Add a definition like this:

```
int myclass::get_a() { return a; }
```

Or just define it inline:

```
class myclass {
    //private to myclass
    int a;
public:
    void set_a(int num);
    int get_a() { return a }; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever *define* `int get_a();` so you get an error at *link-time*.

Include this just above your (rather hubristic) `/*self explanatory*/` comment

```
int myclass::get_a()
{
    return a;
}
```